# How to make Vue Directive as ES6 class?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, es6-class

I want to make Vue directive as ES6 Class, is it possible? because when i'm trying to do it, it doesn't work right.

this is my code:

```
import { DirectiveOptions } from 'vue';
interface WfmCarriageDirectiveModel {
    onFocusDown(): void;
    onKeyDown(event: Event): void;
    resetInput(): void;
    changeOrientation(event: Event): void;
    getNumber(keyCode: number): void;
    getDeflection(keyCode: number): void;
}
const ORIENTATION_VERT = 'vert';
const ORIENTATION_HOR = 'hor';

class WfmCarriageDirective implements DirectiveOptions, WfmCarriageDirectiveModel {
    public startInput: boolean = false;
    public endInput: boolean = false;
    public valueInput: string = '';
    public orientationCarriage: string = '';
    public plan: any = {};
    public rolesMap: any = {};
    public shifts: any = {};
    public onChangeOrientation: any;
    public controlAndInput: any;

    bind(el, binding, vnode) {
        console.log(binding.value.orientationCarriage) // empty stroke;
        this.orientationCarriage = binding.value.orientationCarriage;
        this.onChangeOrientation = binding.value.onChangeOrientation;
        this.controlAndInput = binding.value.controlAndInput;
        this.plan = binding.value.plan;
        this.rolesMap = binding.value.rolesMap;
        this.shifts = binding.value.shifts;

        el.addEventListener('focus', this.onFocusDown);
        el.addEventListener('keydown', this.onKeyDown);
    }

    unbind(el, binding, vnode) {
        el.removeEventListener('focus', this.onFocusDown);
        el.removeEventListener('keydown', this.onKeyDown);
    }

    onFocusDown() {
        this.resetInput();
    }

    onKeyDown(event: Event) {
        if (event.shiftKey && event.keyCode !== 9) {
            return;
        }
        if (event.shiftKey && event.keyCode === 9) {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.changeOrientation(event);
            return;
        }
        if (!event.shiftKey && event.keyCode === 37) {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.controlAndInput({action: 'left'}, this.plan, this.rolesMap);
            return;
        }
        if (event.keyCode === 38) {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.controlAndInput({action: 'up'}, this.plan, this.rolesMap);
            return;
        }
        if (!event.shiftKey && (event.keyCode === 9 || event.keyCode === 39)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.controlAndInput({action: 'right'}, this.plan, this.rolesMap);
            return;
        }
        if (!event.shiftKey && (event.keyCode === 13 || event.keyCode === 40)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.controlAndInput({action: 'down'}, this.plan, this.rolesMap);
            return;
        }
        if (event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 46) {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.controlAndInput({action: 'clear'}, this.plan, this.rolesMap);
            return;
        }
        if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode === 90) {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.controlAndInput({action: 'cancelClear'}, this.plan, this.rolesMap);
            return;
        }
    }

    changeOrientation(event: Event) {
        this.orientationCarriage = this.orientationCarriage === ORIENTATION_VERT ? ORIENTATION_HOR : ORIENTATION_VERT;
        this.onChangeOrientation(this.orientationCarriage);
    }

    getNumber(keyCode: number) {
        ...
    }

    getDeflection(keyCode: number) {
        ...
    }

    resetInput() {
        this.startInput = false;
        this.valueInput = '';
    }
}

export default WfmCarriageDirective;
```

then I add this directive in Main.ts:

```
import WfmCarriageDirective from '@/directives/wfmCarriageDirective';
Vue.directive('wfm-carriage', new WfmCarriageDirective());
```

also part of my template where i'm using directive:

```
<div v-for="(plan, planKey) in planMap[employee.id]"
       :class="[
       `employees-cell ${plan.idEmployee}-${planKey}`,
       {
        'weekend': plan.isWeekend || plan.isHoliday,
       'select': isSelectedCell(plan),
       'vert': isSelectedCell(plan) && isVerticalOrientation(),
       'hor': isSelectedCell(plan) && !isVerticalOrientation(),
       'not-editable': !isEditable(plan)
       }]"
       @mousedown="selectCell(plan, roleId)"
       tabindex="1"
       v-wfm-carriage="{
       plan: {value: plan, key: planKey},
       rolesMap: rolesMap[roleId],
       shifts: shiftsMap.byCode.shifts,
       orientationCarriage,
       onChangeOrientation,
       controlAndInput
       }"
>
```

But unfortunately during component initialization i have an error "Cannot set property 'orientationCarriage' of undefined" and "Error in directive wfm-carriage bind hook: "TypeError: Cannot set property 'orientationCarriage' of undefined"

What am i doing wrong?

How to get access to 'this' in bind hook?

Comment: Try to console.log `this`. I think you don't have access to this context in bind. Because of this message "Cannot set property 'orientationCarriage' of undefined".

Comment: yes, you'r right!! how can i make it available?

Answer (score 0):

Really late, but maybe this helps: Instead of bind, try inserted.

The [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html)

> Hook Functions
> A directive definition object can provide several hook functions (all optional):
>
> - bind: called only once, when the directive is first bound to the element. This is where you can do one-time setup work.
> - inserted: called when the bound element has been inserted into its parent node (this only guarantees parent node presence, not necessarily in-document).
> - update: called after the containing component’s VNode has updated, but possibly before its children have updated. The directive’s value may or may not have changed, but you can skip unnecessary updates by comparing the binding’s current and old values (see below on hook arguments).

Comment: Hello, some explanation on the difference between the two might be useful.